# Emitting a value any time one of several observables emit a value, even if not all have yet?

Tags: rxjs

I have two observables - let's call them A and B. I need to perform the following operations in the following order:

1. Get the latest value of A
2. Get the latest value of B by dispatching an action to my store using the value of A (dispatching the action initiates an async operation that eventually causes B to emit a value)
3. Use the latest values from both A and B to make a decision

The action is dispatched like this (assume `a` is the last value emitted by `A`, and `dispatch` returns `void`)

```
this.store.dispatch(
  new fromStore.LoadItem(a)
);
```

Since B depends on the value of A, I can't use `combineLatest`, since it requires all observables to have emitted at least one value. I would also prefer not to use `merge`, as that would require identifying which observable the value came from, and these are not primitives. It seems like a natural solution would be a version of `combineLatest` that doesn't require all provided observables to have emitted something, but I'm not sure if that exists, or is the proper solution here.

I've made it work in a hacky fashion by subscribing to A and B separately and storing the values globally, but it's messy and I'd like to see if there's a neat means of doing it in a single block of code.

EDIT: trying Fabricio's answer:

```
A.mergeMap(a => { 
  this.store.dispatch(
    new fromStore.LoadItem(a)
  );
  return a
 }, (a, b) => {
   ...
 })
```

I don't understand what I'm supposed to return in the first argument (`a => ???`). B is another observable, I can't pass it the value of A, so `a => B(a)` doesn't work. Do I return `a` after dispatching the action? An observable of `a`? The second observable `B`? In all of these cases I just get `Argument of type '(a: any, b: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.`

Comment: it's not just `A.mergeMap(a => B(a), (a, b) => take ur decision here)`?

Comment: I tried your approach, but I'm getting the following error: `Argument of type '(a: any, b: any) => number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.` Maybe I'm not returning the right thing in the first part of your answer, since I replaced `B(a)` with a `{ ... }` block that dispatches the action and returns the value of A again?

Comment: This would be easier to answer if you included code in your post. The answer is what's in the above comment, but this would be easier with code, as you'd both be referring to the same things.

Comment: What code though? That's why I'm here, I have no idea how to structure this stream. I'd be happy to provide code if you clarified what code would be helpful in making my question more understandable.

Comment: Show this: "I've made it work in a hacky fashion by subscribing to A and B separately and storing the values". Or show what you've done with what I believe to be the correct answer that was given in the first comment. Saying it doesn't work - and effects an error - without showing code is a good way to get your question closed.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up making it work like this:

```
A.mergeMap(a => {
  // dispatch action that causes B to eventually emit a value here
  return B.map(b => {
    // access both results here
  });
});
```

Not sure if Fabricio's answer is the short hand of this or something like that, but I couldn't his version to compile so this is what I'm going with.

Comment: What you did is the same. If `dispatch` returns an observable try returning it like `A.mergeMap(a => this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.LoadItem(a))`. It should work, unless it does not return the value you need

Comment: `dispatch` returns `void`, so maybe that's why it wasn't working.